# Print lines after using match function from regular expressions- Python

Tags: python, regex

So I have written this code that reads a file. From this file I need to extract a certain part of the text. So to start off I used regular expressions to match the beginning of the section of text I wanted:

```
for line in f:
 matchObj = re.search( r'chores \s+ income \s+ .*', f.read(), re.M|re.I)
```

After finding this in the text and printing this line out in the text, there are 7 more lines to print after this text.

So I was thinking to read every line after the matched one and put them into an array, but I've been trying for a long time and don't know how to print the lines after the matched one.

I know how to individually read line by line of the whole text, BUT I don't know how to print after this particular line.

Can anyone help me?

This is not homework, just a project I am working on

EDIT**

So an example input would be:

```
This is a text file containing information I need to get out
some more info
more
ore
re
This is a table of the information
Chores        income      number of chores           cost
cleaning      2.10        1                          40
washing       4.1         4                          60
drying        6.3         5                          20
```

So this is an example text, very random. And using regular expressions I would have found the line  "Chores        income      number of chores           cost"

But the required output would then be:

```
Chores        income      number of chores           cost
cleaning      2.10        1                          40
washing       4.1         4                          60
drying        6.3         5                          20
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and expected output?

Comment: @Rakesh yes I have edited the question to put the example input and output

Comment: You do not need a regex. `for line in f:` -> `if line.startswith("Chores"):` -> `print(line)` (and perhaps add `break` to stop processing lines). See [**the Python demo**](https://ideone.com/9NkYMm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are any non-data lines after the `Chores` heading, you can use a technique like this.

```
# Define the patterns
# HEADER_PATTERN = re.compile(...)
# DATA_PATTERN = re.compile(...)

def parse(line):
    """
    Do whatever it is to the data lines you need
    """
    ...


# Scan the file until you find the header pattern
for line in file:
    m = HEADER_PATTERN.match(line)
    if m:
        break

# Collect the data lines
data = []

# We can use the file again because it remembers how many lines we've
# passed already.
for line in file:
    m = DATA_PATTERN.match(line)

    if m:    
        data.append(parse(line))
    else:
        # No more data lines
        break
```

Comment: what do you mean by non-data lines? So in the example I provided, is it a data line if it contains numerical values? So your answer would not work on that example?

Comment: I meant that a non-data line is any line that is irrelevant to table, and a header line is the labels for the fields in the table, and a data line is a table entry. Why wouldn't this work for your use case?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will be trying this method

Comment: I tried doing this method, however I am finding problems when matching. If say in header_pattern I put the pattern re.complie('Chores \s+ income \s+ .*') it doesn't seem to be matching it as when I put an else statement if m doesnt not match to print false it prints false

Comment: I tried doing this method, however I am finding problems when matching. If say in header_pattern I put the pattern re.complie('Chores \s+ income \s+ .*') it doesn't seem to be matching it as when I put an else statement if m doesn't not match to print false it prints false?

Comment: What about `re.search`?

Comment: I have used a method with re.search and it works, but I wanted to try and use the re.compile because ive been told that it works a lot faster

Comment: You can use the `.search` method on the compiled regex. `pattern = re.compile("...pattern to match on..."); if pattern.search(line): ...`. Almost any function in the `re` module has a method counterpart for compiled regexes